# Squid on Gentoo, get errors on installation

Tags: squid, gentoo

When I try to install squid on my Gentoo

```
emerge squid
```

I get this error:

```
 *                                                                             -
!!! All ebuilds that could satisfy "squid" have been masked.
!!! One of the following masked packages is required to complete your request:
- net-proxy/squid-3.1.22 (masked by: required EAPI 4, supported EAPI 1)
- net-proxy/squid-3.1.23 (masked by: required EAPI 4, supported EAPI 1)
- net-proxy/squid-3.2.5 (masked by: required EAPI 4, supported EAPI 1)
- net-proxy/squid-3.2.6 (masked by: required EAPI 4, supported EAPI 1)
- net-proxy/squid-3.2.7 (masked by: required EAPI 4, supported EAPI 1)
- net-proxy/squid-3.2.8 (masked by: required EAPI 4, supported EAPI 1)
- net-proxy/squid-3.3.1 (masked by: required EAPI 5, supported EAPI 1)
- net-proxy/squid-3.3.2 (masked by: required EAPI 5, supported EAPI 1)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your emerge --info.

Answer (score 0):

Install one of the packages listed 
(#emerge -aDv squid-3.3.2)

should tell you package is masked but include instructions for adding a line to a file such as 'probably net-proxy/squid-3.3.2' to /etc/portage/package.masks 
then just run again (#emerge -aDv squid-3.3.2) this time it should work (type  then press  at the prompt)

Answer (score 0):

Your portage is too old.

```
$ emerge portage
```